# template toolkit - Iterating through array of hashes

Tags: perl, iteration, template-toolkit, dancer

I couldn't find the answer to this one on the web.

Using Dancer and Template toolkit, I have an array of hashes which I would like to print to a table on my webapp. 
This is how I send the data structure to the template:

```
template "find_ip_results2", {
    user => \@user,
};
```

What is the correct foreach syntax to iterate this structure and access each key-value pair?

Comment: What does `@user` look like? Are the elements hashrefs? The way you showed it, this is a hash of arrays, not an array of hashes.

Comment: the array looks something like this :                           $VAR1 = {
          'communities' => 'bar',
          'priority' => ' 3',
          'policyName' => 'TATA',
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'communities' => 'baz',
          'priority' => '1',
          'policyName' => 'Google',
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'communities' => 'foo',
          'priority' => '4',
          'policyName' => 'Peering',
        };

Answer (score 4):

```
[% FOR u = user %]
    [% u.key    # or u.item('key') %]
[% END %]
```

You can read the docs [here](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to eugene y's answer to fix iterator syntax:

```
 <ul>
 [% FOREACH u IN user %]
    <li>
      communities: [% u.communities %]<br/>
      priority: [% u.priority %]<br/>
      policyName: [% u.policyName %]
    </li>
 [% END %]
 </ul>
```